# Java paintComponent(Graphics g) drawn graphics disappear

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

I am new to the graphics and paint on java swing component. I have a few code issue related to these areas.

I have a customJPanel that extends JPanel. Inside the panel, there is a "+" and "-" button to increase the number of image by 1 at a time (minimum 1 image, maximum 50 image). The images are already stored in a list. The buttons are listener that takes care of the add/remove image on the customJPanel:

```
//ADD BUTTON LISTENER
imagePanel.add(imageList.get(i);            
add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);        //customPanel contains a imagePanel(center), and another panel(south)
repaint();
revalidate();
```

Once the images are added, I have a function that draws lines to link the images to a fixed point(x1, y1) on the JPanel.

```
public void drawLinkedLine(){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) imagePanel.getGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for(int i = 0; i < imagesList.size(); i++){
         //some codes to get the image location on the imagePanel

         g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

This method is called by the override paintComponent(Graphics g):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawLinkedLine();
}
```

The issues I am facing now is when I click on the button, it adds/removes 1 image. It suppose to draw line from that image to (x1,y1). However, I can see the lines appear in a flash and disappear. Why would this happening and is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) imagePanel.getGraphics();` is incorrect.  Remove it.  Instead, pass the Graphics object given to your paintComponent method to the drawLinkedLine method.  You can safely cast it to Graphics2D.

Comment: I changed this to use the paintComponent Graphics g. However, it does not have the line drawn on the panel (what I guessed is there maybe another panel on top cover it). Is there a way to bring it up?

Comment: That is solved, I used the setOpaque(false) to make it transparent. Thanks